# how to move one object over another object without bounce in box2d in iphone?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, box2d-iphone

I want to move one object over another object without bounce when they collide.

In Simple i have one ball(body) and i have one Rectangular line image(body), the image is slope 45 degree.

The ball fall from the top speed is 20 when the ball touch on the slope image(Static Body) it will bounce always and continue running.

When the ball come over the line image it will not bounce and slow down the speed according to the collision and ball stop in the end. Same as it happens in real world when ball collide with something , the ball speed will slow down and it turn according to the collision and then stop due to decreasing speed of collision.

I am doing this, but cant achieve the result what i want.

```
 -(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    // Create a world
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    _world = new b2World(gravity);


    /////////////////////////   Ball ///////////////////////////////

    // Create sprite and add it to the layer
    CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
    ball.position = ccp(100, 200);
    ball.tag = 1;
    [self addChild:ball];

    // Create ball body
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(127/PTM_RATIO, 210/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = ball;
    ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);       // b2Body * ballBody

    // Create circle shape
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 26.0/PTM_RATIO;

    // Create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 15.0f;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 2.f;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    _ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);




    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(73, -52);
    ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBodyDef.position);

    //ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(10,0));   // try
   // ballBody->SetAngularVelocity(0);            //  try


    /////////////////////////   Ball ///////////////////////////////







    // Create paddle and add it to the layer
    CCSprite *paddle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"paddle.png"];
    paddle.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 50);
    [self addChild:paddle];

    // Create paddle body
    b2BodyDef paddleBodyDef;
    paddleBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;         //b2_staticBody, b2_dynamicBody
    paddleBodyDef.position.Set(winSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO, 50/PTM_RATIO);
    paddleBodyDef.userData = paddle;
    paddleBodyDef.angle = 75;
    _paddleBody = _world->CreateBody(&paddleBodyDef);

    // Create paddle shape
    b2PolygonShape paddleShape;
    paddleShape.SetAsBox(paddle.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, paddle.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);

    // Create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef paddleShapeDef;
    paddleShapeDef.shape = &paddleShape;
    paddleShapeDef.density = 25.0f;
    paddleShapeDef.friction = 1.1f;
    paddleShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    _paddleFixture = _paddleBody->CreateFixture(&paddleShapeDef);






    // Restrict paddle along the x axis
    b2PrismaticJointDef jointDef;
    b2Vec2 worldAxis(0.0f, 0.0f);
    jointDef.collideConnected = true;
    jointDef.Initialize(_paddleBody, _groundBody, _paddleBody->GetWorldCenter(), worldAxis);
    _world->CreateJoint(&jointDef);


    [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
    self.touchEnabled = YES;
}



- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (_mouseJoint != NULL) return;

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

if (_paddleFixture->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {

    b2MouseJointDef md;

    md.bodyA = _groundBody;
    md.bodyB = _paddleBody;
    md.target = locationWorld;
    md.collideConnected = true;
    md.maxForce = 1000.0f * _paddleBody->GetMass();

    _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md);
    _paddleBody->SetAwake(true);
}
```

// [self kick];

```
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (_mouseJoint == NULL) return;

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

_mouseJoint->SetTarget(locationWorld);





}
```

Comment: give 0 restitution to paddle.

Comment: it is still bouncing sir.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp#dir=XfHFTJBV

Comment: i give you answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so You have mad very small mistak, problem is with gravity.

change it to

```
b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f);
```

Comment: where do i change this line before the world? before the world it is not working. The Ball is not going askew. ball down towards floor at once.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get , what you are saying?

Comment: yes it is working now. Thanks aloot. Thank You very much... Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: How can I move static body (paddle), I want to drag it on runtime. So that I can place under the ball how to drag static body?

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/download/Yp-u4Uc3/Screen_Shot_2013-06-27_at_4573.png?tsid=20130627-121241-65c7e4a6

Comment: You can't move static body,did you check ray wenderlich's tutorial,?
http://www.raywenderlich.com/28604/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-1

Comment: So how can I drag b2DynamicBody? If I use dynamic body and when ball touch the dynamic body it will down towards floor due to gravity and i did not want that. Have you any solution of my problen? Please guide me.

Comment: yes check out link which i have provided in my previous comment. In that they restrict the moment of paddle. You can get clear idea from there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks aloot once again. One more question, I want The ball should start by a force given by user. Like If I pushed hard the ball the force will be high and I give slow jerk the force of ball will become slow. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: what user will do to give more force or less force? Like he will stretch his finger  like in angr bird? Do you want this?

Comment: Yes exactly the same before the ball I want to use trigger. And the ball goes only that direction where the trigger's direction.

Comment: http://dc694.4shared.com/img/Nw7YYLNL/s7/0.5236451860600199/pool.png?async&0.11592474929057062

Comment: ok, i made same thing when i started development in cocos2d iphone, in which i find the first touch location and touch ended location and then i find the length from those two points and one more thing i statically define the maximum length of moved points so with respect to that i will give force on that.